# custom object detection with yolov5

Tags: yolov5

I Have been trying to custom train YOLOv5 model with one label and I have made suitable changes in YAML file .However,
mAP( mean accuracy precision) value is still 0 no matter how many epochs I run the training for. I have been struggling with this issue for many days.
Can someone suggest a solution?

```
 Epoch   gpu_mem       box       obj       cls    labels  img_size
   1/2    0.614G   0.07749   0.03705         0         7       640: 100% 15/15 [00:01<00:00, 10.99it/s]
           Class     Images     Labels          P          R     mAP@.5 mAP@.5:.95: 100% 3/3 [00:00<00:00, 26.59it/s]
             all         12         14          0          0          0          0

 Epoch   gpu_mem       box       obj       cls    labels  img_size
   2/2    0.614G   0.07758   0.03295         0         5       640: 100% 15/15 [00:01<00:00, 10.98it/s]
           Class     Images     Labels          P          R     mAP@.5 mAP@.5:.95: 100% 3/3 [00:00<00:00, 28.13it/s]
             all         12         14          0          0          0          0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem as you. Training seemed to be working correctly, but validation inference kept predicting nothing, resulting in mAP / P / R etc. = 0. This seems to definitely be a software issue. After many painful days of researching I did find a solution that worked for me (warning, I am a software noob/learning CUDA, forgive me for any false speculations, this just worked for me and would like to help others):

Step 1. When creating a virtual environment to install their yolov5 requirements.txt, make sure you specify when creating the environment that you want python 3.9. For some this may be all you need. For me it wasn't.

Step 2. This gets tricky, for me I had problems that CUDA installed being newest 11.7, but cuda toolkit was reporting different version 10.2. I wondered if the toolkit was incorrectly interfacing with pytorch/reporting wrong version or something. Go through steps such that nvcc --version matches your nvidia-smi version AKA get correct CUDA toolkit installation (some PATH modifications post install for linux I needed so it would be correct version, can google post install instructions) From here if you try running train.py you'll get a complaint about pytorch compatibility issues if you have a newer GPU mine was RTX 3090, might be python 3.9 related. To fix this, on the created yolov5 virtual environment, upgrade pytorch to correct cuda version, for me on my linux OS it was conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.6 -c pytorch -c conda-forge.

Step 3. git pull for the yolov5 directory. AKA get any needed updates from yolov5.

And like magic, I finally saw non-zero mAP P R validation values. I hope this helps.